# Android Studio 2.2.2 properties not showing design id

Tags: android, properties

Recently, Android Studio asked me to update plugin, then my computer got turned off. When i turn on back computer and Android Studio, I clicked at text view, and it doesn't show. It is hard for me to change the textsize,textcolor  etc. I had to change it in the text panel. Can someone help me to restore back all the properties?

Image - [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9zoH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clicking that `two blue arrows` button?

[image: Properties]

Clicking that will open the properties window. I think that's what you wanted.